# simple json reading into jqgrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am trying to read following json data into a jqgrid.

```
var myStr =  {  "version" : 2,
        "query" : "java",
        "location" : "suwanee, ga",
        "dupefilter" : true,
        "highlight" : true,
        "radius" : 25,
        "start" : 1,
        "end" : 10,
        "totalResults" : 826,
        "pageNumber" : 0,
        "results" : [

                       {
                        "jobtitle" : "Software Development Team Lead Job",
                        "company" : "GM",
                        "city" : "Roswell",
                        "state" : "GA",
                        "country" : "US",
                        "formattedLocation" : "Roswell, GA",
                        "source" : "General Motors",
                        "date" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 08:21:00 GMT",
                        "snippet" : "principles, techniques and best practices. - Demonstrated expert knowledge in <b>Java<\/b> and\/or .NET. - Demonstrated expert knowledge in building, debugging and... ",
                        "url" : "http:\/\/www.indeed.com\/viewjob?jk=778874434418454d&qd=TOIxqcl1xBNMbg2vKTNLcp5QUXHMUbDABF-wK7BxUqwiE8mPbZ2XU9t5kjdQrB6FlsFPgK13DhJYpBc84nTJQYrzCHZtERhjBNeGyZxL6jI&indpubnum=4675158811138546&atk=18cme6tj519rh3c6",
                        "onmousedown" : "indeed_clk(this, '1050');",
                        "latitude" : 34.021976,
                        "longitude" : -84.35714,
                        "jobkey" : "778874434418454d",
                        "sponsored" : false,
                        "expired" : false,
                        "formattedLocationFull" : "Roswell, GA",
                        "formattedRelativeTime" : "1 day ago"                
    }

                ,


                    {
                        "jobtitle" : "Software Systems Engineer (Java\/J2EE)",
                        "company" : "Universal Business Solutions",
                        "city" : "Alpharetta",
                        "state" : "GA",
                        "country" : "US",
                        "formattedLocation" : "Alpharetta, GA",
                        "source" : "Universal Business Solutions",
                        "date" : "Tue, 17 Dec 2013 18:37:25 GMT",
                        "snippet" : "years experience with <b>Java<\/b> &amp; J2EE Must be motivated... environment. Experienced with <b>Java<\/b>, J2EE, Oracle, UNIX, SQL, Unix Shell script, <b>Java<\/b> Script, MVC Desired... ",
                        "url" : "http:\/\/www.indeed.com\/viewjob?jk=7066b95f71004292&qd=TOIxqcl1xBNMbg2vKTNLcp5QUXHMUbDABF-wK7BxUqwiE8mPbZ2XU9t5kjdQrB6FlsFPgK13DhJYpBc84nTJQYrzCHZtERhjBNeGyZxL6jI&indpubnum=4675158811138546&atk=18cme6tj519rh3c6",
                        "onmousedown" : "indeed_clk(this, '1050');",
                        "latitude" : 34.074177,
                        "longitude" : -84.29121,
                        "jobkey" : "7066b95f71004292",
                        "sponsored" : false,
                        "expired" : false,
                        "formattedLocationFull" : "Alpharetta, GA",
                        "formattedRelativeTime" : "8 days ago"                
    }

                ,


                    {
                        "jobtitle" : "Software Engineer",
                        "company" : "ACI Worldwide",
                        "city" : "Norcross",
                        "state" : "GA",
                        "country" : "US",
                        "formattedLocation" : "Norcross, GA",
                        "source" : "ACI Worldwide",
                        "date" : "Thu, 19 Dec 2013 11:51:00 GMT",
                        "snippet" : "\u2022 Experienced <b>Java<\/b> engineer for developing commercial... development experience \u2022 2 years of professional <b>Java<\/b> development with 2+ years of J2EE. \u2022 2 years of... ",
                        "url" : "http:\/\/www.indeed.com\/viewjob?jk=7ac5988d9e5f0990&qd=TOIxqcl1xBNMbg2vKTNLcp5QUXHMUbDABF-wK7BxUqwiE8mPbZ2XU9t5kjdQrB6FlsFPgK13DhJYpBc84nTJQYrzCHZtERhjBNeGyZxL6jI&indpubnum=4675158811138546&atk=18cme6tj519rh3c6",
                        "onmousedown" : "indeed_clk(this, '1050');",
                        "latitude" : 33.93956,
                        "longitude" : -84.20879,
                        "jobkey" : "7ac5988d9e5f0990",
                        "sponsored" : false,
                        "expired" : false,
                        "formattedLocationFull" : "Norcross, GA",
                        "formattedRelativeTime" : "6 days ago"                
    }

        ]
    };


$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    //url: "testData.xml",
    dataType:"json",
    data : myStr,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "results"
    },
    colNames: ["Trending Jobs"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "url" }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    loadonce: true
});
```

I tried to read the data using jsonreader, set the data type as "json" and root as "results".

There are no data populated in jqgrid, Could anybody educate me, what I am missing here ?

Comment: how are you trying to read it

Comment: $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    dataType:"json",
    data : myStr,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "results"
    },
    colNames: ["Trending Jobs"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "url" }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    loadonce: true
});

Comment: I changed the text "dataType" to "datatype" and tried with "json" and "jsonstring" values, but not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code there are because of small misunderstanding about the meaning of the options jqGrid. If you define a variable like `myStr` in your code

```
var myStr = {
        "version" : 2,
        ...
        "results" : [
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    };
```

you *don't use JSON*. It's just usage of **object literals** to create new object. Such syntax is the most simple and effective way to create and initialize an object in JavaScript. Only if properties have special characters it's required to enclose property names in `"` or `'`. So the same code can be rewritten as

```
var myStr = {
        version : 2,
        ...
        results : [
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    };
```

So I wanted to stress that the above don't use JSON at all. The correct value of `datatype` parameter (not `dataType`) should be `"local"` instead of `"json"`. The options `jsonReader` or `loadonce` will be ignored in the case. The input data should be array of items specified by `data` option of jqGrid.

So the fixed code should be like the following

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: myStr.results,
    colNames: ["Trending Jobs"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "url" }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto"
});
```

(see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sri1.htm)).

If your real code do load the data from the server it should use `url` parameter. In the case the options `jsonReader` or `loadonce` can be used and the code will be like below

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "Sri2.json",
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "results"
    },
    loadonce: true,
    colNames: ["Trending Jobs"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "url" }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto"
});
```

(see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sri2.htm)).

You code have strange properties like `onmousedown`. If you need to set `onmousedown` property on some cell you can use `cellattr` property in `colModel`. It allows you to set any *additional* property to `<td>` element which represent the cell of the grid. For example [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sri1_.htm) uses the following code

```
function indeed_clk (obj, id) {
    alert("onmousedown with id=" + id);
}
$(function () {
    var myStr = {
            ...
            "results" : [
                {
                    ...
                    "onmousedown" : "indeed_clk(this, '1050');",
                    ...
                }
            ]
        };
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: myStr.results,
        colNames: ["Trending Jobs"],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "url",
                title: false,
                cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject) {
                    if (rawObject.onmousedown) {
                        return 'onmousedown="' + rawObject.onmousedown + '"';
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, 10000],
        pager: "#pager",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "auto"
    });
});
```

It set `onmousedown` attribute which calls *global* function `indeed_clk`. `onmousedown` will be set on the cells in the column `url` using `cellattr` property.

Comment: @Oleg..can you please..help me on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786045/how-to-disable-save-handler-on-jqgrid-while-doing-editing

Comment: @Oleg..i am not sure.how SaveRow and EditRow works, because i am manually savin them not using inbuilt functionality to save. So, i am finding trouble to stop those events firing..PLease help..

Comment: Thank you Oleg! I would use the information you provided. I would like to add this information to understand jqGrid in deeper. The data "myStr" would be coming from server in real time and I verified the data on jsonlint.com and it is a valid json. Is "jsonReader" used only for the data coming from server side ? Is datatype "local"  used when data is on client page irrespective of data is xml, array or object type of data ?

Comment: @Sri: If you load the data from the server then you should specify `url` parameter, use `datatype: "json", jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "results"}, loadonce: true` (see [my second example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sri2.htm)). jqGrid will makes asynchronous Ajax call to the server URL onece and will fill the grid. `datatype: "local"` works in another way, the input data have another format. One can use [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) for customization.