# How to disable Save Handler on Jqgrid while doing editing

Tags: jqgrid, edit

I am working on an ASP.net MVC 4.0 application with Jqgrid.

I am **making all rows as editable** with some columns being editable and some non editable.

The Problem here is , i dont want to use Save and ESC handlers.

I am saving row details on the blur event of one of the text boxes. and still i need to stay in **EDIT** Mode.

So, if the user mistakenly presses enter , the row is going out of edit mode.

How to disable these **Esc** and **Save** Handlers

Please help..

**Updated:**

**I am not using either cell edit  or inline editing or form editing**.

I am converting all rows as editable on the loadComplete trigger of the Jqgrid

i have only one Column being editable. that is of type **Textbox**

So, on the blur event of it , i am  saving that to database using an ajax post .

Every thing is working fine upto this.

Here, **the grid needs to be in edit mode even after saving value to database**.

But, when clciking on enter on that row, it is moving out of edit mode  which violates my requirement

**I need to stop row moving to View mode from edit mode when ESC or Enter Keys are pressed**

I hope this is clear..if not i will mention more..

Comment: The text of your question is unclear. What editing mode you use? Which "Save Handler" you mean? What code you use? Do you edit local data or save the data on the server? Sorry, but I really have no idea what you do.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation..I will update the question

Comment: @oleg..can you please check my edited question..

Comment: @Oleg..Please find my answer below..and suggest.

Comment: Rather than using gridComplete to turn on editing, why not use a custom formatter to render the column as a text input with a onblur, you can save the rowid as a data attribute of the input to get back the row from the jqgrid onblur. Btw, there is a keys option on editparameters that may also get you want you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it in this way:

Dont know whether it is right way of doing this:

Oleg..i need your views on this:

```
    if(cnt > 0) {
        svr.id = rowid; $t.p.savedRow.push(svr);
        $(ind).attr("editable","1");
        $("td:eq("+focus+") input",ind).focus();
        if(o.keys===true) {
            $(ind).bind("keydown",function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 27) {
//                  debugger
//                  $($t).jqGrid("restoreRow",rowid, o.afterrestorefunc);
//                  if($t.p._inlinenav) {
//                     try {
//                        $($t).jqGrid('showAddEditButtons');
//                     } 
//                     catch (eer1) {}
//                  }
                    return false;
                }
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
//                  var ta = e.target;
//                  if(ta.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') { return true; }
//                  if( $($t).jqGrid("saveRow", rowid, o ) ) {
//                      if($t.p._inlinenav) {
//                          try {
//                              $($t).jqGrid('showAddEditButtons');
//                          } catch (eer2) {}
//                      }
//                  }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridInlineEditRow", [rowid, o]);
        if( $.isFunction(o.oneditfunc)) { o.oneditfunc.call($t, rowid); }
    }
```

This is the code , i found in the **Jqgrid.src.js**

Since, i done need restoreRow and saveRow to be called when <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed, i commented out the code .

**I dont know if it is right way to do it. but, this worked indeed for my Scenario.**