# jQgrid : Disable inline Save and Esc Handler while editing grid Row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am developing a asp.net MVC 4 project which uses jQgrid for generating table data.In my generated grid i am providing an inline edit option for particular columns in a row.

My problem is like while editing a particular row if i press `Enter` or `Esc` key my selected row is going out of edit mode.

I want to disable those events Enter and Esc .

I googled about this problem and i get some interesting posts [How to disable Save Handler on Jqgrid while doing editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786045/how-to-disable-save-handler-on-jqgrid-while-doing-editing)

Here in the above reference post i can see that some of the lines are commented out from `Jqgrid.src.js` file which i dont think as a best solution.

Is there any other method so that i can disable both `Enter` and `Esc` Event in Jqgrid while doing inline editing.

Javascript COde

```
jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid({
        url: baseUrl + '/api/Controller/method',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'col1', index: 'col1', align: 'center', editable: true, key:true },
        { name: 'col2', index: 'col2', align: 'center' },
        { name: 'col3', index: 'col3', align: 'center', editable: true, key:true },
        { name: 'col4', index: 'col4', align: 'center' },
        { name: 'col5', index: 'col5', align: 'center', editable: true, key:true }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'data',
            id: 'col2',
            repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#Pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        autoencode: true,
        multiselect: true,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        caption: "Record"

        });
```

Sample Grid Structure

[image: Sample Grid Image]

Note: Grid Image shown is not the actual grid generated with the above code.

Here in the above grid there are some columns are left editable.My scenario is like i want to put data in all editable column in each row , so that i can update the grid data to server by a button click placed below the grid(Button not shown in the above image).Here i am not using editUrl property of grid.

Currently if i edit first row and accidently if i press enter or Esc key the selected row will become non editable.I want to keep all editable cells in a row as editable untill i press the Submit button placed below the Grid.

My jQgrid Version is 4.5.4

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to answer on the question which don't contains neither JavaScript code nor exact references on jqGrid version which you use. You don't describe in which form you use inline editing in the grid.

The usage of <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> during inline editing can be managed by `keys: true` option. The exact syntax of the usage of `keys` option depend on *how* you use inline editing. For example you can call [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) directly or use some other methods mile [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) or the [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) which calls `editRow` for you. The default value of `keys` option is already `false`, so you change the value somewhere in your code to `true`.

Comment: I think this is correct, I think he is looking for the keys param.

Comment: I believe key: true is for setting the primary Key.

Comment: @Cyber: The code which you posted contains syntax error `'Col5]` instead of `'Col5']` (see `colNames`). You should remove `,` before closing `}` (see `caption: "Record"`). Additionally you use `myType: "POST"` instead of `mtype: "POST"`, so default `mtype: "GET"` will be used. You question is about **editing**, but your code don't contains anything which shows how you use inline editing. There exist property `key: true` in `colModel`, but there are the option `keys: true` during inline editing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out syntax errors.I have updated my post and set key:true to all my editable fields.Is this a right method or should i have to set key:true to some other place in my code.

Comment: @Cyber: I wrote you before that your problem is in `keys` and **not** `key`. Usage of `key: true` for more as one column or for the column which don't have unique values is wrong. So your current code with usage of `key: true` is definitively false. Moreover you use `id: 'col2'` in `jsonReader` which contradict with `key: true` for other columns. Could you append your question with the code which shows **how you start/use inline editing**? You have problem in editing, but the code which you posted *contains no editing*.